# Unable to refresh the listview after deleting item using action sheet in Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

i have a listview with some items retriving form the server

```
<div
            id="getbookmarks"
            data-role="view"
            data-title="my bookmarks"
            data-before-show="app.views.showgetbookmarks.beforeShow"
            data-show="app.views.showgetbookmarks.show"
            data-layout="default" >


        <div data-role="touch" >

                    <ul  id="listview-getbookmarks"  data-role="listview" data-endless-scroll="true" data-template="mF"></ul>

                    <div data-role="actionsheet" id="companyActionsList"  data-open="app.views.showgetbookmarks.onOpen" data-close="app.views.showgetbookmarks.onClose" data-popup='{"direction": "left"}'  >

                        <li><a  href="#" data-action="app.views.showgetbookmarks.reply"  class="km-button delete">Delete</a></li>

                    </div>
            </div>


    </div>
```

the template looks as follow

```
                        story Title <div class="h2">#= storyTitle #</div>


                      <p    data-role="button" data-rel="actionsheet" href="\\#companyActionsList" data-actionsheet-context="#: id#">Delete</p>

                    </a>




</script>
```

and the function for deleting the item using ajax looks as the follow ..i am able to delete the element but listview is unable to reload automatically.after delete

```
reply:   function (e) {

                console.log("done"+ e.context);


                          var deleteid= e.context;

                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({


                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: kkkkk.getServiceUrlJson() + "? hello"
                            ,type: "POST"
                            ,dataType: "json"
                            ,data: {
                                bookmarkId:deleteid

                            }
                            ,xhrFields: {
                                withCredentials: true
                            }
                        }
                    }


                });
                dataSource.read();



        },
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, try to put this code inside the click event

```
$("#listview-getbookmarks").data('kendoMobileListView').dataSource.data().remove($(this)[0].dataItem);
```